What is BluetoothGattDescriptor?
As referenced in Android doc for BluetootGattCharacteristic:
Represents a Bluetooth GATT Descriptor. GATT Descriptors contain additional information and attributes of a GATT characteristic, BluetoothGattCharacteristic. They can be used to describe the characteristic's features or to control certain behaviours of the characteristic.
A BluetoothGattDescriptor describes the features or to control BluetoothGattCharacteristic. But there is a method to read the BluetoothGattDescriptor from a remote device:
BluetoothGatt.readDescriptor
Reads the value for a given descriptor from the associated remote device
Why can the value of a descriptor be read from a remote device? It describes a characteristic, so I thought it should be stitched with the BluetootGattCharacteristic, isn't it? What kind of value does it read from remote device?

The best way to understand this is through a better understanding of the BLE GATT profile. In BLE, there are multiple ways of exchanging data between devices but by far the most common and mostly used one is GATT. In GATT data exchange, one device acts as the GATT server (the device that hosts the data) and GATT client (the device that reads the data). Think of a GATT server as a structured database where data is organized into tables, and the GATT client reads that data through BLE communication (similar to querying specific rows and columns in a database).Traditionally, GATT servers are devices like sensors, where the sensor type (e.g. heart rate sensor) and sensor data (e.g. 78 beats per minute) are organized in the GATT table.
A  GATT table is usually structured as follows:-

Services: these are a collection of characteristics (e.g. Heart Rate service, Blood Pressure service, etc).
Characteristics: these are the actual datapoints within a service. For example, the Heart Rate service will have a Heart Rate Value characteristic, a Sensor Location characteristic, etc. Likewise, the Blood Pressure service will have a Blood Pressure Value characteristic, a Blood Pressure Feature characteristic, etc.
Descriptors: These provide additional info about characteristics or allow the remote user to control the characteristic behaviour. For example the CCCD descriptor (0x2902) allows enabling or disabling the notifications/indications of a specific characteristic. The CUD descriptor (0x2900) contains additional characteristic properties.


Below is an image which shows what you see through a GATT client app reading from a GATT server. As you can see, there are usually multiple services (e.g. Heart Rate service) containing multiple characteristics (e.g. Heart Rate Measurement, Body Sensor Location, etc). In the image, the CCCD descriptor allows the user to enable notifications on that characteristic. In other words, if "1" is written to the CCCD descriptor, you will start receiving the Heart Rate Measurement value continuously without requesting to read it. When you write "0" to the CCCD, the GATT client will stop receiving the value unless you explicity read it.

This is just one example of a descriptor, and there are multiple that do different things as can be seen in the link below.
https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Files/Specification/Assigned_Numbers.html#bookmark109
This answer is just scratching the surface and I recommend looking at the links below for more info on the BLE GATT profile and specifically the role that GATT descriptors play:-

O'Reilly GATT services and characteristics
Generic Attribute Profile (GATT)
BLE characteristics, a beginner's tutorial

